# How could I generate a contextual tree using python?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, tree, iteration

Please, I need to generate a contextual tree as follows, I work with python as many advise me that it is one of the best languages for this type of programs. The problem that I have to solve is as follows:

I have 3 vectors

- `v1 = [0, 1]`
- `v2 = [0, 1, 2]`
- `v3 = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]`

Knowing that my initial vector `IV=[0,0,’a’]`, I need to generate a tree of all the possible next vectors based on the following conditions:

- if `v1=0`, in the next level `v1` can take two possible values  `v1=0` or `v1=1`, but if `v1=1`, it never comes back to 0, so it will be always equal to 1 (v1=1)
- Whatever the value of v2, in the next level it will always generate all the possibilities,  `v2=0`, `v2=1` and `v2=3`
- If `v3=’a’`, then in the next level v3 is either `v3=’a’` or `v3=‘b’` ; If `v3=’b’`, then in the next level v3 can be equal to `v3=’a’` or `v3=‘b’` or `v3=‘c’`; If `v3=’c’` then in the next level, v3 is either  `v3=‘c’` or `v3=‘b’`

So from the first vector `[0,0,a]-> [0,0,a] [0,0,b] [0,1,a] [0,1,b] [0,2,a] [0,2,b] [1,0,a] [1,0,b] [1,1,a] [1,1,b] [1,2,a] [1,2,b]`

Then for each generated vector, I have to do the same treatment until I reach 5 levels of the global tree.

Could you help me please?

I started by this code to generate the first level , but now I 'm stuck on generating the next levels while satisfying the conditions below:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
v1 = [0, 1]
v2 = [0, 1, 2]
v3 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
array = [v1, v2, v3]
AllCombinations = list(itertools.product(*array))
m1 = np.asarray(AllCombinations)
root = (0, 0, 'a')
```

Comment: What code have you tried?  SO is not a coding service, it is to help people solve problems that they can't solve. I.e. the asker should have at least tried something.

Comment: I started with the following code: 
    import numpy as np
    import itertools
    v1 = [0, 1]
    v2 = [0, 1, 2]
    v3 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    array = [v1, v2, v3]
    AllCombinations = list(itertools.product(*array))
    m1 = np.asarray(AllCombinations)
    root = (0, 0, 'a')
Now m1 is a matrix (18*3). How can I start treating vector by vector while applying the conditions that I need

Comment: Put it in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Please can you help me??

Comment: Can you add an example for another `root`? Then I can probably get it

Comment: Let's take an example with 2 variables v1=[0,1] and v2=[‘a’,’b’,’c’], where:
-if v1=0 then in the next level v1 is either v1=0 or v1=1 and if v1=1, then it still always 1
-if v2=’a’ then in the next level v2 equal to ‘a’ or ‘b’; if v2=’b’ then in the next level v2 is either ‘a’ or ‘b’ or ‘c’; if v2=’c’ then in the next level v2 equals to ‘c’ or ‘b’
1st level: [0’a,’] -> [0,’a’], [0,’b’], [1,’a’], [1,’b’]
2nd level: 
[0’a,’] -> [0,’a’], [0,’b’], [1,’a’], [1,’b’]
[0,'b'] -> [0,’a’], [0,’b’], [0,’c’][1,’a’], [1,’b’], [1,’c’]
[1,'a'] -> [1,’a’], [1,’b’]
[1,'b'] -> [1,’a’], [1,’b’], [1,’c’]

Comment: Added that to your question... Also that example is a little confusing but it may be because it is not formatted right. Please put it in the question. Also don't change your vectors on me. It adds to the confusion. Just give another root for the example you already gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
import itertools

def get_combinations(v1, v2, v3, v1_root, v2_root, v3_root):
    # using the list and roots
    # fidn the list we actually want combination for.
    v1 = v1[v1.index(v1_root):]
    # v2 = v2[v2.index(v2_root):]
    if v3_root == 'a':
        v3 = ['a', 'b']
    elif v3_root == 'c':
        v3 = ['c', 'b']
    return list(itertools.product(*[v1, v2, v3]))


v1 = [0, 1]
v2 = [0, 1, 2]
v3 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
array = [v1, v2, v3]
root = (0, 0, 'a')

t = get_combinations(*array, *root)
print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 0, 'a'), (0, 0, 'b'), (0, 1, 'a'), (0, 1, 'b'), (0, 2, 'a'), (0, 2, 'b'), (1, 0, 'a'), (1, 0, 'b'), (1, 1, 'a'), (1, 1, 'b'), (1, 2, 'a'),(1, 2, 'b')]
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much, that's can solve my problem, but is it possible to create a new list for each iteration in loop for?? So that after generation the first list I can do the following:

    for item in t:
    root = t[t.index(t)]
    NewList(i) = get_combinations(*array, *root)

Comment: I am confused with your example. Add an example to your question of what you want and I can change the code for that

Comment: As I need to generate a tree, I need to repeat the same treatment for each generated item in the list t. For that, I added the following lines: 

    t = get_combinations(*array, *root)
    array2 = []
    for item in t:
        root = t[t.index(item)]
        t = get_combinations(*array, *root)
        array2.append(t)

Array2 is a list of lists [[[0,0,'a'],...[1,1,'b']],[.....],[....]...], and to be able to repeat the treatment as much time as I need, I have to save each sublist separately in a new variable L[i], but I didn't find any way to do that.

Comment: You data doesn't have a tree structure though it has a linked list structure.  Please add what you want to your question not in the comments. It is hard to read code in comments.  You should not be pasting code examples in the comments. Put it in your question. Put several example inputs and the outputs you want for each input and I can help (in your question NOT the comments).  Your comment is still to vague to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you so much, that's can solve my problem, but as I need to generate a tree, I need to repeat the same treatment for each generated item in the list t. For that, I added the following lines:

```
    t = get_combinations(*array, *root)
    array2 = []
    for item in t:
    root = t[t.index(item)]
    t = get_combinations(*array, *root)
    array2.append(t)
```

Array2 is a list of lists [[[0,0,'a'],...[1,1,'b']],[.....],[....]...], and to be able to repeat the treatment as much time as I need, I have to save each sublist separately in a new variable L[i], but I didn't find any way to do that.
Let' say I have [[1,1,1][1,0,1][1,0,0]], I need to use a for loop to get the following result: List1=[1,1,1] List2=[1,0,1] List3[1,0,0]